# Permutations, Recursion

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

I have an assignment: User enters a String, example ABCD and the program has to give out alll the permutations.
I don't want the whole code just a tip. this is what i got so far in thery i got nothing implemented.

Taking ABCD as an example:

get factorial of length of String in this case 4! = 24.

24/4 = 6 So first letter has to change after 6. so far so good.

than get factorial of remaining letters which are three 3! = 6.

6/3 =2 2 places for each letter. from here i don't know how it can continue to fill 24 places.

With this algorithm all i will have is

ABCD

ABD

AC

AC

AD

AD

B

B

B

B

B

B

.

. (continues with 6 C's and 6 D's)

I think my problem is i do not have alot of experience with recursive problems so who can suggest some programs to program to help me get to know recursion better please do.

Thanks! If somethings aren't clear please point out.

Comment: Thanks! You meant like this right?

Comment: [Permutations.java](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/23recursion/Permutations.java.html)

Comment: Yes it can change a small example of a permutation is entering ABC - these are its permutations ABC,ACB,BAC,BCA,CAB,CBA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that recursion is the way to go.  The example you worked thru w/ the little bit of math was all correct, but kind of indirect.

Here's some pseudocode:

```
 def permute(charSet, soFar):
     if charSet is empty: print soFar //base case
     for each element 'e' of charSet:
         permute(charSet without e, soFar + e)  //recurse
```

example of partial recursion tree

```
                      permute({A,B,C}, '')
                   /           |           \
 permute({B,C}, 'A')  permute({A,C}, 'B')   permute({A,B}, 'C')   
                          /          \
               permute({A}, 'BC')    permute({C}, 'BA')
                       |
               permute({}, 'BCA')<---BASE CASE, print 'BCA'
```

---

### EDIT

To handle repeated characters without duplicating any permutations.  Let `unique` be a function to remove any repeated elements from a collection (or string that is being treated like an ordered character collection thru indexing).

1) Store results (including dupes), filter them out afterwards

```
 def permuteRec(charSet, soFar):
     if charSet is empty: tempResults.add(soFar) //base case
     for each element 'e' of charSet:
         permute(charSet without e, soFar + e)  //recurse

 global tempResults[]

 def permute(inString):
     permuteRec(inString, '')
     return unique(tempResults)

 print permute(inString)
```

2) Avoid generating duplicates in the first place

```
 def permute(charSet, soFar):
     if charSet is empty: print soFar //base case
     for each element 'e' of unique(charSet):
         permute(charSet without e, soFar + e)  //recurse
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit further cause i didn't fully understand it so the base case will be an empty string?
my idea of the base case was both empty and just 1 character of a string.

Comment: My Base case:
if length of string is less than 2 print 
0 for an empty string, Same string for a 1 character string.

Comment: on the first call `charSet` will be collection containing all n elements and `soFar` will be empty.  on base cases `charSet` will be empty and `soFar` will contain all n elements.  `soFar` must be ordered, `charSet` can be ordered or unordered

Comment: i dont really follow your idea of base case.  what string do you mean when you say 'length of string'?

Comment: Thank you very much for helping do you know of any excersises to improve recursion?

Comment: The String that the user enters if it is just one letter or empty. I think i'm looking at this problem from the wrong way.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! i got the hang of this one, and hope that with your suggestions will improve in recursion.

Comment: recursion exercises - write a recursive factorial function (this is tail recursion, single recursion call, can also be done iteratively),try to implement a mergesort after this (binary recursive) get familiar with tree structures (it is a recursive structure) and implement one. write something for fibonacci sequence. check out related questions on the right. add printout of arguments at the beginning of every recursion call so you can follow where the recursion goes (or use language construct for a stack trace) and get familiar with the stack. you kind of need to build an intuition for it.

Comment: you didnt have a bad idea with 'The String that the user enters if it is just one letter or empty' but remember it doesnt need to be what the user input, it can be several recursion layers later.  it just needs to be the argument to the function.

Comment: What if the user enters a string that contains duplicate characters, like `"AABC"`?

Comment: The pseudocode i originally posted did not consider this, and as such would output some duplicates.  It hasnt too tough to handle tho, I posted two ways.

Answer (score 0):

Make a method that takes a string.

Pick a letter out of the string and output it.

Create a new string with the input string minus the letter you picked.

call the above method with the new string if it has at least 1 character

do this picking of one letter for each possible letter.